# Hyper-reference for acronym in long/short form

Tags: hyperref, acronyms

I am using the `acronym`-package to create a list of acronyms used in the document. In some cases, I would rather use the long form and introduce the short form separated with a comma instead of in brackets.

Using `\acl{}` and `\acs{}` works, but does not mark the postion for the hyper-reference as shown in the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused, withpage]{acronym}

\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}[AC1]
    \acro{AC1}{Acronym 1}
    \acro{AC2}{Acronym 2}
    \acro{AC3}{Acronym 3}
\end{acronym}

I would like to introduce an acronym in brackets and comma-separated (\acl{AC1}, \acs{AC1}) but
still mark the position for the hyper-reference. However, a warning is produced instead of the
reference as it would be for \ac{AC2}.
\end{document}
```

This returns a warning: `Hyper reference 'acro:AC1' on page 1 undefined`.
Is there a way to produce the same output while marking the position for the reference?

Comment: Are you bound to `acronym` or would a solution with `acro` also a possibility?

Comment: That depends on compatibility. I would rather not go back and change all instances in my document.

Comment: never mind. `acro` has no option for linking from the list back to the acronyms in the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the needed label manually:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused, withpage]{acronym}
\makeatletter
\let\ACplacelabel\AC@placelabel
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}[AC1]
    \acro{AC1}{Acronym 1}
    \acro{AC2}{Acronym 2}
    \acro{AC3}{Acronym 3}
\end{acronym}

I would like to introduce an acronym in brackets and comma-separated (\ACplacelabel{AC1}\acl{AC1}, \acs{AC1}) but
still mark the position for the hyper-reference. However, a warning is produced instead of the
reference as it would be for \ac{AC2}.
\end{document}
```