# Inconsistent colours with acronym package

Tags: xetex, acronyms

The following example produces an acronym list, where some items are coloured (and work as hyperlinks), whilst others are not:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{css-colors}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{final=true,
            pdfauthor={Dr. Engelbert Buxbaum},
            colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=Blue,%bibliography, dark blue
            linkcolor=Blue,%internal links, dark blue
            urlcolor=DodgerBlue,%internet, middle blue
            allbordercolors=White}

\begin{document}

The \acs{16PF} and the \acf{EJI} measure personality factors, \acf{COMP}, \acf{GPA}, \acf{MCAT} and \acf{MLE} measure students performance.

\begin{acronym}[COMP]
   \acro{16PF}{16 Personality Factors}
   \acro{COMP}{NBME Comprehensive Shelf Exam}
   \acro{EJI}{Emotional Judgement Inventory and Report}
   \acro{GPA}{grade point average}, summary of student's performance at college
   \acro{IPAT}{Institute for Personality \& Ability Testing, Inc.}, manufacturer of \acs{16PF} and \acs{EJI}
   \acro{MCAT}{Medical College Admissions Test}
   \acro{MLE}{Medical Licensing Exam}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image: output of above example]

Note that the listing of both 16PF (referred to in the text) and IPAT (not referred to) are black, the others blue.

Why is that, and how can I obtain a more consistent output?

Thanks in advance

Engelbert

Comment: Did you notice the warning you get when compiling your document? I get warnings such as "Hyper reference acro:16PF on page 1 undefined" and "Hyper reference acro:IPAT on page 1 undefined". Both are caused because you did not use `\acf{16PF}` nor `\acf{IPAT}` in your document.

Comment: [Hyper-reference for acronym in long/short form](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/580880/134144) and [Problem with \acs from acronym package: No link in list of acronyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39088/134144) seem to be somewhat related.

Comment: For this example use   `\acf` instead of `\acs`  to get the right colors.

Comment: Yes, that does solve the problem with colours. However, in a short document, one would not necessarily want to use \acf when there is a list of acronyms, say, on the same page.

Comment: Indeed https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39088/problem-with-acs-from-acronym-package-no-link-in-list-of-acronyms seems a direct duplicate, with a solution that allows using `\acs`.

Comment: Yes, the use of \acsu instead of \acs solves the problem.